# Laravel Ressource, check specific user

Tags: php, controller, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using a ressource controller and it is possible to edit a user like this: users/edit/8 (8 is the id).

How can I check that only user 8 can edit his account?

Because another user could set any ID in the URL and edit any account.

I could use:

```
if (!Auth::user()->id === $id) { 
   //throw exception ... 
}
```

But that is not the point of laravel "dont repeat yourself".

Should I use ressource controllers for user related stuff (like account settings etc) ?
Or just for admin related stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be `$id`?:

```
if (!Auth::user()->id === $id) { 
   // still throw exception? Which one?
}
```

If you don't want a user to be able to have access to a particular route 'users.edit', then you need to create a filtered route:

```
Route::get('users/edit/{id}', array(
                         'as' => 'users.edit', 
                         'before' => 'auth|checkUser', 
                         'uses' => 'UserController@edit'
                         )
);

Route::filter('checkUser', function($route, $request, $value)
{
    if (! Auth::use()->id === $route->parameter('id'))
    {
        return Redirect::to('operation-not-permitted-route');
    }
});
```

As you are using RESTful controllers, this route should be added before your `Route::controller()` command.

This is one way. Another one would be to create a new controller just for your profile stuff and create specific routes and filters for this controller.

About using RESTful and Resourceful routes, I always like to point this post from Phil Sturgeon: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil.

Comment: That's true I forgot the $ - but how can I avoid the "if" because I dont want to use the if everytime I need to check for the user. | I fixed the $ in my question above